# $\mathbb E[X_i\mid X_1,...,X_n]=\mathbb E[X_i]$

Tags: conditional-expectation

Do you agree that if $(X_i)$ is a sequence of i.d.d. random variable, then for all $i$

$$\mathbb E[X_i\mid X_1,...,X_n]=\mathbb E[X_i]\ \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 9):

I don't agree.  Given the outcomes of all $X_i$ you know exactly what the conditional expectation is, namely, $X_i$ for $i \leq n$.
$$E[X_i | X_1, ..., X_n] = X_i$$
That's true regardless of if the sequence are iid or not.

Since the $X_i$ are independent, this does hold true for $i > n$
$$E[X_i | X_1, ..., X_n] = E[X_i]$$

Comment: This reminds me a bit of the fun task to expand the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\cdots (x-z)$ :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Could you please explain it?

Comment: @echo What is the factor between $(x-w)$ and $(x-y)$?

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very well. I'm not sure to understand everything.  So idd or not,  if $i>n$ $$\mathbb E[X_i\mid X_1,...,X_n]=\mathbb E[X_i]$$ right ? And if $i\leq n$ what happens ?

Comment: No, for independent and $i > n$ that statement holds true.  For $i \leq n$ the expected value is just what you observed for the variable itself $X_i$.  This is just the statement that $E[X | X] = X$.